# Dirac delta integral as a coefficient

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Can anyone solve this?
$$
\int_{0}^{t} \exp\left(\frac{t}{9}\right) \delta(t_1-t)\,dt.
$$
I need to solve it and wikipedia says it might result to $\exp(t/9).$

Comment: Use $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~ f(t)\delta(t - t_1) = f(t_1)$$

Comment: Thanks, so if we integrate from t zero until t, it would result in to exp(t/c)?

Comment: It would be $f(t_1)$ provided $0 < t_1 < t$

Comment: \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{0} \delta(x)dx  +  \int_{0}^{\infty} \delta(x)dx = 1

Comment: is the above comment means anything here

Comment: $t$ is the integration variable $\color{#f00}{\mbox{AND}}$ $t$ is the integral upper limit $\color{#f00}{\mbox{TOO}}$. Please, clarify your post !!!.

Comment: There can be two approaches here, one to have the upper bound set as a fixed time(e.g. t(100)) or to have the upper bound as infinity. I appreciate the replies in advance